# Cardinality of a quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, cardinals, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

Suppose there exists a bijection $f: A\rightarrow B \ /\  C$, where $ B \ /\  C$ denotes a quotient set "$B$ mod $C$."

If there are $b$ elements in B and $c$ elements in $C$ (i.e. both $b$ and $c$ are finite), can we say the cardinality of $A$ is just $\frac{b}{c}$?

Comment: You cannot make a quotient of sets. However, you can make a quotient of groups, rings by ideals, vector spaces... well you need an algebraic structure, in which case this is true (provided that it is finite though). If you are in such case, $|B/C|=|B|/|C|$ is a general consequence of the fact that $B\to B/C$ is a map whose fibers are all equipotent to $C$.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Thanks! For the last sentence, do you mean "whose fibers are all equipotent to $B/C$" instead, since $B\rightarrow B/C$ is a surjection? Also, how do you conclude $|B/C|=|B|/|C|$ from this equipotent relationship?

Comment: I did mean "[...] equipotent to C". Let $\pi:B\to B/C$  be such quotient map, a fiber for $\pi$ is $\pi^{-1}(\{b\text{ mod } C\})$ for $b$ mod $C$ any element in $B/C$. If you carefully look at what does the quotient mean, you will see that  $\pi^{-1}(\{b\text{ mod } C\})$ is the set of all elements in $B$ that are "equal to $b$ up to an element of $C$". It is not hard to see that this set is in bijection with $C$.

Comment: For the second question you can always express $B$ as a disjoint union $B=\bigcup_{x\in B/C}\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$. Since this is a disjoint union by applying the cardinal map $|B|=\sum_{x\in B/C}card(\pi^{-1}(\{x\}))$ and using what I have just said $card(\pi^{-1}(\{x\}))=|C|$ which is independent of $x$, thus the equality simply becomes $ |B|=|B/C||C|$ whence the result.